# Required timer count for a number of same frequency different duty cycle PWM signal

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, pwm, timer

Ok, it may look a bit confusing. I am specifically talking about STM32 MCUs, or even more specific, [STM32F103C8T6](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f103c8.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwizt9rk8OPpAhVLUMAKHWi8AEAQFjAAegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw0rd6I_7fuhTLdZOoycvGV5). I did some amount of reading, but could not find the answer to this.

Let's say I want 4 PWM signals each at 50 Hz but all with different duty cycles. In such a case will I need 4 distinct timers, or can I use one timer with 4 channels? I mean can each channel of same timer be configured with different duty cycle?

Comment: What did you think a channel was for if not this? The answer, by the way, is in the fact that each channel has it's own register.

Comment: @DKNguyen I am no sure but maybe for using same timer for both PWM and input capture for example.

Comment: Fair enough. But then what if there were 4 channels (which there should be on most timers).

Comment: *Its own count register

Comment: The count register determines when a channel triggers (for output compare) or what timer count it captures (for input capture).

Comment: @DKNguyen I back then(about a year ago) dealed with timers pwm etc. with an stm32 mcu. But since then I forgot most of the concepts. I remember setting ARR for overflow of the timer and there was some register about comparing, by which I was determining duty cycle. So, from your sayings and my past knowledge(if can remember things correctly) there is(should be) a distinct compare register for each channel of a timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why timers have multiple channels, to generate multiple PWM signals with same timer. If you use multiple separate timers, their output may not be synchronized.

Comment: ok, this answers my question, but, what about frequency? is it common for every channel of a timer? or can be different?

Comment: @muyustan Frequency is common because they all run off the same clock and pre-divider so all channels count at the same time.

Comment: All channles run with a single timer so they must have identical frequency.

Comment: @DKNguyen thank you both.